# Converting Blob object to html in google app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have stored user uploaded document (.doc ,.pdf) as a Blob object into data-store.
Instead of allowing user to download the document, I would like to present it as an HTML page
for viewing the doc. how do I convert Blob into HTML ? does google app engine provides any ready made API for the same?

Comment: What do you mean by "allowing to download"? If you want to prevent users from downloading the documents, it's a different problem.

Comment: Hi Andrei,I am not preventing the download option  but I am providing a way to view the document even before downloading.

Answer (score 2):

There is no ready made API in AppEngine to convert .doc or .pdf (or or other types of) files to HTML.  You would need to find a library for your preferred language to parse the blob file into its parts structured as an object model (like a DOM).  Then you would need to write code to convert individual parts of the object model to HTML, unless you are lucky enough to find another library.  And no, StackOverflow is not a good place to ask "what library is there...".

Answer (score 1):

No. AppEngine itself does not provide any file format conversion tools. You might want to look into Google Drive API, which might, to some extent, do the format conversion for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can have embed a PDF reader on a web page by using [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers already have a built-in PDF viewer. If you provide a link to a PDF file, when users click on it, many browsers will automatically display the document. Those browsers that do not support this option, will offer a user to download the file to their hard-drive.

This is the easiest solution - you don't have to do anything at all.